GPSD can not get access to /dev/pts
I have tried and tried to get GPSD to access NMEA data on my /dev/pts/2 device but I can not seem to make it happen. I have tried to change permissions to 777 still doesn't work. I can cat the /dev/pts/2 file and I see NMEA data plain as day but GPSD just keep saying it does not have permission.  I tried to alter the /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.gpsd file.
I added
/dev/pts[0-9]*        rw,
# default paths feeding GPS data into chrony
  /{,var/}run/chrony.tty{,S,USB,AMA,pts}[0-9]*.sock rw,

I restarted apparmor still same errors.
I added my user to the tty group as well as the root user. No help
The errors occur in both my local user and the root user.
Thanks for any help. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a desk top
gpsd:INFO: stashing device /dev/pts/2 at slot 0
gpsd:PROG: no /etc/gpsd/device-hook present, skipped running ACTIVATE hook
gpsd:INFO: SER: opening GPS data source type 6 at '/dev/pts/2'
gpsd:ERROR: SER: device open of /dev/pts/2 failed: Permission denied - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: SER: read-only device open of /dev/pts/2 failed: Permission denied
gpsd:ERROR: initial GPS device /dev/pts/2 open failed
gpsd:ERROR: can't run with neither control socket nor devices open


See at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them

I found my problem and it was a mistake I made in the /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.gpsd file. I put this in the usr.sbin.gpsd file
/dev/pts[0-9]*        rw,
It should have been
/dev/pts/[0-9]*        rw,
Also the pts portion should be removed from this statement
/{,var/}run/chrony.tty{,S,USB,AMA,pts}[0-9]*.sock rw,
It now works with /dev/pts/[0-9]* as a device that gpsd can access.
I was so close yet so far
